# Can you access IP addresses user tries to connect to?

Tags: java, android

I want to access information from my app what page user visiting using whatever browser they want. Is it possible to do that on Android, and if so how?

Answer (score 2):

not sure about android but in java you can do it in following way

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
if (ipAddress == null) {
    ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
}
System.out.println("ipAddress:" + ipAddress);
```

see original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324466/finding-user-ip-address)

Comment: Does it allow me to get information about other applications? As in my application will know what happens in browsers?

Answer (score 2):

That would be a security vulnerability if it could be done. Your app would be able to spy on users credentials when posted, or track/hijack their sessions. I guess you can do this by building a proxy (like what HotSpotVPN does) and routing your phones traffic through the proxy. Therefore you can log visited pages in your proxy.

Comment: But there are applications that block your access to certain websites basing on their IP access.

Comment: That would be [different](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398841/how-to-block-some-url-on-android-browser). anyhow I think you can try accessing your phone's browser history. [This](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Accessing-Data-With-Android-Cursors/3/) is a sample and of course you need [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577084/android-read-browser-history) permission.